# Why PhpSpreadSheet is not reading cell values?

Tags: php, excel, xlsx, phpspreadsheet, phpoffice

I'm trying to read some cell values from a `.xlsx` file using **PhpSpreadSheet**, but I don't know why this isn't working. The file opens but when I read the values of the cell it returns nothing. I have checked that the filename is correct and that cells have data. I want to read the **SECOND** sheet of the file, that why I have used `getSheet(1)`.

This is my code:

```php
use PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\IOFactory;   

$inputFileType = 'Xlsx';
$inputFileName = 'Test.xlsx';


$reader = IOFactory::createReader($inputFileType);
$reader->setReadDataOnly(true);
$spreadsheet = $reader->load($inputFileName);
$sheet = $spreadsheet->getSheet(1);


$filterHours = $sheet->getCell('D309')->getOldCalculatedValue();
$otherHour = $sheet->getCell('D295')->getOldCalculatedValue();
$title = $sheet->getCell('B297')->getOldCalculatedValue();

printf($title);
printf($filterHours);
printf($otherHour);
```

EDIT: If I use `getCalculatedValue()` instead of `getOldCalculatedValue()` I get this error:

> **Fatal error**: Uncaught PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Calculation\Exception:
>   Configurador!D309 -> Configurador!D745 -> Configurador!D755 ->
>   Configurador!C776 -> **Formula Error**: An unexpected error occured in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\OfferConfigurator\vendor\phpoffice\phpspreadsheet\src\PhpSpreadsheet\Cell\Cell.php:274
>   **Stack trace**: #0
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\OfferConfigurator\php\generateDocumentation\prueba.php(26):
>   PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Cell\Cell->getCalculatedValue()
>   #1 {main} thrown in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\OfferConfigurator\vendor\phpoffice\phpspreadsheet\src\PhpSpreadsheet\Cell\Cell.php 
>   on line 274

Can that be because `Configurador!C776`  has a formula that references to another sheet?

Comment: Are you sure you're reading the correct sheet? The first sheet will be 0.

Comment: I know, but I want to read the second sheet. That´s why the index is 1

Comment: Just checking as it's a simple mistake I would make.

Comment: I would suggest testing "Looping through cells" on this page: https://phpspreadsheet.readthedocs.io/en/latest/topics/accessing-cells/#looping-through-cells

Comment: it will be helpful to provide the content of your excel file and also the output of your code.

Comment: @nngeek Sorry, but I can´t provide the content of the excel due to confidential issues. But I can tell you that the cells that I wanted to read are related with cells from another sheet. Can that be the problem?

Comment: Sometimes by multible redirection of the Cell errors occur can you provide the content of dthe cell D309 and all there called formulas and values?

Answer (score -1):

Try degrading your Phpspreadsheet version to 1.8.2.